# Can Windows Event Log capture fewer events?

Tags: windows-10, event-log

Is it possible to configure the Event Log to record only events above a specific severity level?

On one Windows 10 Home PC, there are currently **1,123 separate Event Logs**, from `AMSI/Debug` to `Windows.Globalization/Analytic`. Is there a way to control globally what *types* of events are captured, such as in Java's [Log4j](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Log4j)?

`Log4j` can be configured to capture only fatal errors, or other error levels such as Error, Warning... all the way to Debug and Trace. However, the Windows Event Logs seems to be capturing *everything*, which causes constant writing to disk and overwriting old log data. Some events are spurious, such as [TDL events](https://www.ghacks.net/2018/12/29/windows-10-user-profile-service-event-id-1534-warnings/).

[BTW, though I'm seeking to do this to reduce disk usage, could this be a cause of early SSD death on Windows machines? Though write-caching may reduce the total number of storage operations, having that many active logs would seem likely to have *some* impact on disk usage. It would be useful to compare at different levels of logging.]

Comment: "there are currently 1,123 separate Event Logs, from AMSI/Debug to  Windows.Globalization/Analytic" On WIn7 Most of those are empty or only have a couple of events ...

Comment: You can right click > properties on many logs and disable them. A max size can be set for any logs.

Comment: @DavidPostill, Thanks, I realize each log can be completely disabled... but I'd like to record events at higher levels, just not verbose information.

Answer (score 0):

What gets logged in Windows is determined by the settings within individual applications or Windows services. You can control logging by disabling individual event logs (except for the Classic event logs), but you cannot control which events get logged on a global scale in Windows.

> I'm seeking to do this to reduce disk usage

Even on a very busy workstation, disk I/O from logging is not significant enough to have a meaningful impact on storage performance. If it is, then the real problem is that your storage subsystem is malfunctioning.

For proof events don't create a significant strain on storage I/O, make note of the maximum size of some of your event logs then observe how many hours or days it takes to fill that log. From that you can calculate how many KB per hour/minute/second are written to the log. You will quickly discover than even an enormous number of events translate into a trivial amount of total data written per second.

Comment: Regrettably, though Windows is operating normally, some logs *are* filling rapidly, with multiple writes per minute. One example given was TDL, Tile Data Model Service, which has been removed from Windows 10, but parts have accidentally been left behind, continually adding events for issues with the removed service. That particular issue has been fixed by me, but logs are being cluttered with other junk.